# Authentication user on another server then access to download file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 2 servers for one site. First server have php and mysql but second server only have php (is download host).
My site is about selling videos and because the first server is restricted (Monthly traffic and space), I need to upload videos on second server. All videos must be have dynamic link and all links must be disposable.

**Example:**

1. User1 bought video `abc`, this user have below link to download:                 `http://example.com/1enewk3hd`  (refers to 
   `http://example.com/files/video_abc.mp4`)
2. User2 bought video `abc`, this user have below link to download: `http://example.com/sddfse445`  (refers to 
   `http://example.com/files/video_abc.mp4`)
3. Users must be can't download video by real link `http://example.com/files/video_abc.mp4`

**My Questions**

1. Is able this scenario on 2 server (without mysql) by PHP and htaccess?
2. If yes, Please guide me what's the best way to authentication user on
   second server then access to download file (without mysql)
3. On some sites, When user logged in on server 1, can download from
   server 2. If logout from server 1, then can't access to server 2.
   How do this? We can't use session from server 1 on server 2!

Comment: Yes there are an incredible amount of different ways you can authenticate someone without needing a database. However, if the only solution you know and confident with involves MySQL, why don't you allow server2 to contact the database on server1?

Comment: @WillParky93 thanks dear, but how to connect server 2 to db server 1? is not slowly?

Comment: It will be slower than a local connection, but fast enough to not see a difference. Contact server1 host and ask them to add a rule to allow your database to accept connections from server 2. You can whitelist none local IPs to connect in mysql.

Comment: I believe the standard way is to implement a kind of SSO with token-based authorization. E.g. [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/) where server1 act as a provider and server2 act as a client. Otherwise nothing stops User1 to share the link http://example.com/1enewk3hd with other users.

Answer (score 1):

Let the first server do the authentication.
Create on the first server links, which are valid for x minutes. Protect that link for manipulations with a hash.

hash=sha256(validuntil+shared secret on both servers)

Sample:
https://server2/video_abc.mp4?validuntil=2017-08-07_160000&hash=ABC123EF5244

(in my sample i would also use mod_rewrite for a nice url)

Now redirect the client to the new server with the generated link.
A php script validates the query parameter "validuntil" and "hash" by using the shared secret. then check if validuntil is expired or not.

if not stream the file. do not place the streamed files into the webroot.
They are send by the php script with [readfile](http://php.net/manual/de/function.readfile.php) or by your webserver if you are able to use [x-sendfile header](http://blog.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/).

Comment: Thanks dear, but links must be disposable. how to do this?

Comment: On some sites, When user logged in on server 1, can download from server 2. if logout from server 1, then can't access to server 2. How do this?

Comment: a link is only valid for 5 minutes (or whatever timeout you set). if required include remote ip to limit the link even more. When you have a really big cluster, you will be flooded with requests if a session is valid. this is a offline solution. yes a link cant be disable instantly but who cares about 5 minutes? think about the more effort you need to do and what is the benefit.  About instant disable a login: how do you want to cancel already running downloads.

Comment: An other solution are use once tokens, which are verifyed on loginserver. but this creates problems if download mangers are used, when they open many connections.